# Big size difference in ibdata file from live to staging

Tags: mysql-5.5, ibdata

I have a mysql server running on AWS Instance. The server has a schema of around `8 GB` which is the main schema.

I have two environments staging and live. The live has only one schema i.e. `live_schema` where as the staging database has multiple schemas with different time stamp like `live_copy_03207...` which are copy of live. So the total database size on staging is around `50 GB`.
I am using InnoDB engine for the database.
Here's the issue. The live `ibdata` file is `4.2 GB` where as the staging `ibdata` files is only `187 MB`.

What could be the reason for this huge difference between `ibdata` size from live to staging? I know it only grow and there no shrinking, I know to shrink/cleanup the file I am required to backup the database and delete everything and restoring the database.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you have or had in the past `innodb_file_per_table=0`, and despite separating them at a later stage into separate files (changing it to 1+rebuilding the tables), the space, as you said, has not been reclaimed.

In most cases, **ibdata1 growing too much is caused by extra temporary space needed in the UNDO area** (which before 5.6, was always part of the ibdata1 file). The usual problem happens this way: A long transaction starts (**a long running query, a non-closed transaction** by mistake, etc.)- all subsequent edits cannot purge the old data because in repeatable read mode, a transaction after the first select goes into "snapshot mode". As a consequence, the UNDO space keeps growing and growing, and your queries start getting slower and slower. This is very typical in production hosts that have high write activity but also have to backup consistently the database or perform statistics-like queries.

There are other reasons why this could happen, but the long running transactions is the #1 cause (aside from former bad configuration). If the long running transactions are no longer active, know that data is available for new pages within the file, just not returned to the filesystem- so unless it happens again it may not grow again. As you said, either export+import is the only way to shrink it before MySQL 5.6.

You have more information on how and what ibdata1 is used for at: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/08/20/why-is-the-ibdata1-file-continuously-growing-in-mysql/ Many of the pains of tablespace handling were fixed on 5.6 (UNDO on an external file, importing/exporting .ibds, querying ibdata structure contents,...) so give at some point a chance to 5.6 testing, it may be worth in your case.